# How to deal with hyphens in php namespace links etc?

Tags: php

I am using symfony package. The link to the package is like this:

`use vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;`

The error I am getting is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting ',' or ';'

I have never seen this problem before clearly it is the hyphen, I have looked around and I have not seen anything to help. I have seen some examples of dealing with variables with hyphen in them. Should I use a variable for http-foundation, and do something like `{'http-foundation'}`?

Comment: `{'http-foundation'}` looks like the problem...

Comment: So should I do something like `$link = {'http-foundation'}` then put the variable in the link?

Comment: nope that is not working, tried it, `$link = {'http-foundation'}` has an error of its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a class provided by composer's autoloader you only need the following:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
```

The 'vendor\symfony\http-foundation\' part is not needed.

You may need to include the autoloader first if its not already:

Be sure to use the correct path to the autoloader in the vendor directory.

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
```